# SQL statement that retrieves formulas for two different dates in db

Tags: sql

All,

I have three total tables.  The first table 'rollup1' contains the number of views and number of clicks for a campaign, as well as a one-up number for the day field (largest number in column represents the current date) A second table 'rollup2' contains the earnings for the campaign. It also contains the same one-up number for the dayfield. The third table 'campaigns' contains the ID/names for the campaigns.  campaigns.id = rollup1.id = rollup2.id and rollup1.day=rollup2.day

I want to generate an SQL query that lists the campaign id, name, specific calculated value from yesterday, and specific calculated value from today.  The specific calculated value I'm looking for is (earnings/clicks)*1000.

The results will look like:

```
id | name | yesterday | today
a  | Campaign1 | $0.05 | $0.010
```

I think I can use case statements, but I can't seem to get it correct.  Here's what I have so far.  It calculates the formula for yesterday, but not the one for today.  I need these to be side by side.

```
select campaigns.id, campaigns.name, rollup1.views,rollup1.clicks,rollup2.costs,round((rollup2.costs/rollup1.views)*1000,2) as yesterday
 from campaigns,rollup1,rollup2
 where campaigns.id = rollup1.campaign_id and campaigns.id = rollup2.campaign_id 
and rollup1.dayperiod = rollup2.dayperiod
and rollup1.dayperiod = (SELECT (max(rollup1.dayperiod) -1) FROM rollup1)
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Comment: More info will be needed on table structure.  For example, the meaning of "one-up number for the day-field".  In general I think you are asking for a simple answer to a complicated problem, and I think it doesn't make for a good question.

Comment: `...and rollup1.dayperiod = (SELECT (max(rollup1.dayperiod) -1) FROM rollup1)` The scalar subquery indicates that is is probably a mysql-thingy.

Comment: Yes...this is a MySQL database.  The dayperiod column in the rollup1 and rollup2 tables is an integer number that just adds one number per day.  Think of today as 10000, yesterday as 9999, day before yesterday as 9998.

As for table structure, they're a bit complicated, but in the 'Campaigns' table, the only columns needed are ID and Name of Campaign.  The rollup1 table has 4 columns - ID,views,clicks,dayperiod.  The rollup2 table has 3 columns - ID,costs,dayperiod.